# Angular @ngtools/webpack build fails when using webpack mode 'production'

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ngtools

I've been having the issue, that as soon as I set

```js
{ mode: 'production' }
```

in my `webpack.config.js` my Angular templates that have been declared using

```js
@Component({ templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html' })
```

could not longer be compiled.

The resulting errors were all related to directives used in the template, e.g.

```
src/path/to/template.html:1:123 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the error gives more information than it may seem. The issue is actually, that it's been changed from `routerLink` to `routerlink`.

When the production mode is active, the `html-loader` enables it's minimizer. Since the loader is used for fetching the templates *before* it's passed to the Angular compiler, this sets up the error.

The easiest way to fix this issue, is to set the `caseSensitive` option of the `html-loader` to `true`

```js
{
  module: {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: { caseSensitive: true } }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm documenting this here, so I can hopefully find it when I search for it in 2 or 3 years from now.